# Problem converting Postgres text field to timestamp field ignores format

Tags: postgresql

Postgres 90611
When trying to convert a string field `(file_original_create_datetime)` to a new timestamp field `(new_original_create_datetime)` using the following SQL, the results only include the time, and not the date.

```
update files  
set new_original_create_datetime = to_timestamp(file_original_create_datetime, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') ::timestamp without time zone at time zone 'Etc/UTC'
```

[image: Input Data]

Comment: What is the error you are getting, I suspect you want to run an alter table statement here

Comment: Notice that the resulting column "new_original_create_datetime" in image does not contain the YYYY-MM-DD.  I wanted to preserve the original data, so I created a second column to contain the converted data.

Comment: Check the type of `new_original_create_datetime`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works here:

```
select to_timestamp('2019-02-28 21:15:01', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss')::timestamp without time zone at time zone 'Etc/UTC';                                                                
+------------------------+
| timezone               |
|------------------------|
| 2019-02-28 22:15:01+01 |
+------------------------+
```

If the type of the column `new_original_create_datetime` is `timestamp`, the  `UPDATE` should work.

Comment: Doh....  The field was set as "Time" because I got lazy when typing "Timestamp" and tried to use autocomplete!!!